# cublas matrix multiplication not as expected

Tags: c, gpu, matrix-multiplication, cublas

I am trying to replace my gpu block matrix multiplication with cublas but I am not getting what I expect on a 2x2 test case:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "cublas_v2.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "omp.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  const int SZ = 2;
  const size_t MB = SZ*SZ*sizeof(float);

  cudaSetDevice(0);

  float *m1, *m2, *m3;
  float *m1_, *m2_, *m3_;

  unsigned int i, j;

  m1 = (float *)malloc(MB);
  m2 = (float *)malloc(MB);
  m3 = (float *)malloc(MB);

  cudaMalloc((float **)&m1_, MB);
  cudaMalloc((float **)&m2_, MB);
  cudaMalloc((float **)&m3_, MB);

  for (i=0; i<SZ*SZ; i++) {
    j = (int) (i==1);
    m1[i] = j;
    j = (int) (i==3);
    m3[i] = j;
    printf("m1[%d]=%f m3[%d]=%f\n",i,m1[i],i,m3[i]);
  }

  cublasHandle_t handle;
  cublasCreate(&handle);

  cublasSetMatrix(SZ,SZ,MB,m1,SZ,m1_,SZ);
  cublasSetMatrix(SZ,SZ,MB,m3,SZ,m3_,SZ);

  float al = 1.0f;
  float bt = 0.0f;

  cublasSgemm(handle,CUBLAS_OP_N,CUBLAS_OP_N,SZ,SZ,SZ,&al,m3_,SZ,m1_,SZ,&bt,m2_,SZ);
  printf("\n%s\n\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaDeviceSynchronize()));
  cublasGetMatrix(SZ,SZ,MB,m2_,SZ,m2,SZ);

  for (i=0; i<SZ*SZ; i++)
    printf("m2[%d]=%f\n",i,m2[i]);

  free(m1);
  free(m2);
  free(m3);

  cublasDestroy(handle);

  cudaFree(m1_);
  cudaFree(m2_);
  cudaFree(m3_);


  cudaDeviceReset();

  return 0;
}
```

So I expect for `m2` to return the following matrix:

```
[0 1
 0 0]
```

as a result of the multiplication of

```
[0 1
 0 0]
```

and

```
[0 0
 0 1]
```

I am using the reversed order for `m1` and `m3` so that should give me the correct output for `m2` when retrieved given that cublas{Set/Get}Matrix works in column-major. But here is the output of the code:

```
m1[0]=0.000000 m3[0]=0.000000
m1[1]=1.000000 m3[1]=0.000000
m1[2]=0.000000 m3[2]=0.000000
m1[3]=0.000000 m3[3]=1.000000

no error

m2[0]=0.000000
m2[1]=0.000000
m2[2]=0.000000
m2[3]=0.000000
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here; I would very much appreciate your input.

Comment: The `#include "omp.h"` line is of course irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype of *cublasGetMatrix* is:

```
cublasStatus_t cublasGetMatrix(int rows, int cols, int elemSize, 
                        const void *A, int lda, void *B, int ldb);
```

*elemSize* should be the size of one element of the Matrix (i.e. `sizeof(float)` ). It is the same for *cublasSetMatrix*:

```
cublasStatus_t cublasSetMatrix(int rows, int cols, int elemSize,
                        const void *A, int lda, void *B, int ldb)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! Do you by any chance know if I could replace the `cublasGetMatrix` with `cudaMemcpy` to avoid the column-major hassle and perform the matrix multiplication in the normal order (for row-major input)?

Comment: Sure you can. But should then either store your matrix with content in column major... or use cublasSgemm with the transpose options if you are sure the transpoed matrices will be the same as the column major version. Also I would recommand using cudaMemcpy2D  to get a good alignment (maybe you will have to adjust the LDx parameters when calling the Sgemm)

Comment: Ah, I see; I thought copying with `cudaMemcpy` would automatically copy the matrix in the right order for `cublas` to utilize regardless of whether it represents row- or column-major input. I see where I went wrong in my thinking; thank you again!